# Creating safe SQL statements as strings

Tags: c#, .net, sql, concatenation, stringbuilder

I'm using C# and .NET 3.5. I need to generate and store some T-SQL insert statements which will be executed later on a remote server.

For example, I have an array of Employees:

```
new Employee[]
{
   new Employee { ID = 5, Name = "Frank Grimes" },
   new Employee { ID = 6, Name = "Tim O'Reilly" }
}
```

and I need to end up with an array of strings, like this:

```
"INSERT INTO Employees (id, name) VALUES (5, 'Frank Grimes')",
"INSERT INTO Employees (id, name) VALUES (6, 'Tim O''Reilly')"
```

I'm looking at some code that creates the insert statements with String.Format, but that doesn't feel right.  I considered using SqlCommand (hoping to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/how-to-get-the-generated-sql-statment-from-a-sqlcommand-object)), but it doesn't offer a way to combine the command text with parameters.

Is it enough just to replace single quotes and build a string?

```
string.Format("INSERT INTO Employees (id, name) VALUES ({0}, '{1}')",
    employee.ID,
    replaceQuotes(employee.Name)
    );
```

What should I be concerned about when doing this?  The source data is fairly safe, but I don't want to make too many assumptions.

EDIT: Just want to point out that in this case, I don't have a SqlConnection or any way to directly connect to SQL Server.  This particular app needs to generate sql statements and queue them up to be executed somewhere else - otherwise I'd be using SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue()

Comment: AddWithValue is great (I use it often), BUT it can suffer from the wrong implicit type conversion if not used carefully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use parameterised commands. Pass the parameters along to your remote server as well, and get that to call into SQL Server, still maintaining the distinction between the SQL itself and the parameter values.

As long as you never mix treat data as code, you should be okay.

Comment: Just going to bed now, actually. Preaching tomorrow morning 10.30-11.30, so you're guaranteed a good crack at the whip then! ;)

Comment: Preaching? Are there recordings?

Comment: @tofutim: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide a solution when it's a hard requirement that the output is an `.sql` script file with ready-made `INSERT` commands with the data to be inserted.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Indeed - note that the OP added that requirement after I'd answered, although they still accepted my answer, oddly enough...

Comment: @JonSkeet: True - probably fine for the OP, yet somewhat annoying for future visitors who actually face the problem as described in the question.

Answer (score 19):

Create your SqlCommand object like so:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Employees (id, name) VALUES (@id, @name)", conn);

SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@id";
param.Value         = employee.ID;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@name";
param.Value         = employee.Name;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Using "cmd.AddWithValue("@id", employee.ID);" is much terser.

Comment: I get that every so often and got that on my answer to this one as well.

Comment: Brad Wilson: An extra ".Parameters" is needed: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", employee.ID);`

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP clearly states they do not have access to the DB and instead need to output commands that can be run at a later time.

Answer (score 5):

Fix your replace quotes function this way:

```
string replaceQuotes(string value) {
     string tmp = value;
     tmp = tmp.Replace("'", "''");
     return tmp;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: It is much easier to use the parameters, think about all the characters that must be escaped. And also this is not SQL injection safe.

Comment: @KarelFrajták: How can the parameters be used when the formatted commands are only going to be executed later (presumably, after execution of the C# code has finished), as described in the question?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, in that case, I would queue the statements and a dictionary with parameters names and values.

Comment: @KarelFrajták: *"this is not SQL injection safe"* Really? I challenge you to provide a concrete `value` such that `"INSERT INTO Employees (name) VALUES ('" + replaceQuotes(value) + "');"` leads to SQL injection on any recent version of SQL Server. If you can provide such a `value`, I will reward a question or answer of your choice with 500 rep.

Comment: Did anyone come up with any value for this?

Comment: NOTE: The temporary "tmp" is not needed. Also, in modern c#, this can be shortened to `string replaceQuotes(string s) => s.Replace("'", "''");`

Comment: @Heinzi it may be thread safe, but I won't put my hand in fire for that. Using parameters is much easier. Similarly, I am not going to write my own hashing mechanism, since it has already been done and verified before.

Comment: @KarelFrajták: I fully agree, and I'd never use "replacing quotes" when parameters are an option. Nevertheless, the question whether "replacing quotes" is insecure or not is a valid and interesting question, not only from a scientific point of view, but also because there are (unfortunately) edge cases where parameters are not an option. From my personal experience, "replacing quotes" is secure, but not correct. For correctness, you also need to (at least) [escape line breaks and create Unicode string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76270817/87698).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper going back to square one, I must say there's no easy way, I haven't noticed your request to execute the SQL later ... but I have found this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305558/how-does-use-of-sp-executesql-with-parameters-protect-against-sql-injection) discussing usage of `sp_executesql`  where you can get some inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I agree with everyone else that you should be using parameterized queries and will leave it at that. But how are you going pass these sql statements to your remote server? Do you have some type of service like a web service which will accept and execute arbitrary Sql commands or is your client app going to hit the DB directly?

If your going through some sort of proxy then no matter how much you sanitize your data on the client, a hacker could just bypass your app and hit the service. In which case do what Cade recommends and pass the data as XML for example or whatever format you choose (JSON, Binary etc..) Then build your SQL right before you actually run the command.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid injection, you need to ship the data to the remote server (perhaps in XML) and then on the remote server, the data should be converted back to appropriate data types and used in parameterized queries or stored procs.