# Drop Down list null value not working for selected text c#?

Tags: c#, database, drop-down-menu, null

Basically I have a drop down list which is populated with text and values depending on a selected index of a radio button list. The code is as follows:

```
protected void RBLGender_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DDLTrous.Items.Clear();
        DDLShoes.Items.Clear();
        if (RBLGender.SelectedValue.Equals("Male"))
        {

            String[] MaleTrouserText = {"[N/A]", "28\"", "30\"", "32\"", "34\"", "36\"", "38\"", "40\"", "42\"", "44\"", "48\""};
            String[] MaleTrouserValue = { null, "28\"", "30\"", "32\"", "34\"", "36\"", "38\"", "40\"", "42\"", "44\"", "48\"" };
            String[] MaleShoeText = { "[N/A]", "38M", "39M", "40M", "41M", "42M", "43M", "44M", "45M", "46M", "47M" };
            String[] MaleShoeValue = { null, "38M", "39M", "40M", "41M", "42M", "43M", "44M", "45M", "46M", "47M" };
            for (int i = 0; i < MaleTrouserText.Length; i++)
            {
                ListItem MaleList = new ListItem(MaleTrouserText[i], MaleTrouserValue[i]);
                DDLTrous.Items.Add(MaleList);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < MaleShoeText.Length; i++)
            {
                ListItem MaleShoeList = new ListItem(MaleShoeText[i], MaleShoeValue[i]);
                DDLShoes.Items.Add(MaleShoeList);

            }

        }

            else if (RBLGender.SelectedValue.Equals("Female"))`
```

When the text '[N/A]' is selected I want the value NULL to be inserted into the database. At present when '[N/A]' is selected the value entered into the database is [N/A] does anyone know why?

This is my DB insertion code:

```
protected void UpdateWorkWear()
    {



        try
        {

            string connectionString = Common.GetConnectionString("w34to4tmConnectionString");

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder();


            string str = DDLSurname.SelectedValue;

            if (str.Contains("'"))
            {
                str = str.Replace("'", " ");

            }

            sbSQL.Append("IF EXISTS (select * from TO4_WORKWEAR_DISTRIBUTION where EmpID = @EmpID)");
            sbSQL.Append(" UPDATE TO4_WORKWEAR_DISTRIBUTION SET ");
            sbSQL.Append("costCentre = coalesce(@Cost_Centre, CostCentre), EmployeeType = coalesce(@EmployeeType, EmployeeType), Initials = coalesce(@Initials, Initials), Surname = coalesce(@Surname, Surname), ");
            sbSQL.Append("IssueQuarter = coalesce(@IssueQuarter, IssueQuarter), TrouserSize = coalesce(@Trouser_S, TrouserSize), TrouserLength = coalesce(@Trouser_L, TrouserLength), ");
            sbSQL.Append("PoloSize = coalesce(@Polo_S, PoloSize),  SweatSize = coalesce(@Sweat_S,SweatSize), ShortSize = coalesce(@Short_S, ShortSize), ShoeSize = coalesce(@Shoe_S, ShoeSize) WHERE EmpID = @EmpID ");
            sbSQL.Append(" else INSERT INTO TO4_WORKWEAR_DISTRIBUTION (EmpID,CostCentre, EmployeeType, Initials, Surname, IssueQuarter, TrouserSize, TrouserLength, PoloSize, SweatSize, ShortSize, ShoeSize) ");
            sbSQL.Append("VALUES (@EmpID, @Cost_Centre, @EmployeeType, @Initials, @Surname, @IssueQuarter, @Trouser_S, @Trouser_L, @Polo_S, @Sweat_S, @Short_S, @Shoe_S)");




            sbSQL.Replace("@EmpID", "'" + DDLEmpID.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Cost_Centre", "'" + DDLCostCentre.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@EmployeeType", "'" + RBLAssociate.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Initials", "'" + DDLInitials.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Surname", "'" + str + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Trouser_S", "'" + DDLTrous.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Trouser_L", "'" + DDLTrouserLnh.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Trouser_Q", "'" + DDLTrouserQty.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Polo_S", "'" + DDLPolo.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Polo_Q", "'" + DDLPoloQty.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Sweat_S", "'" + DDLSweat.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Sweat_Q", "'" + DDLSweatQty.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Shoe_S", "'" + DDLShoes.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@Short_S", "'" + DDLShor.SelectedValue + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@InputDate", "'" + System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'");
            sbSQL.Replace("@IssueQuarter", "'" + RBLQuarter.SelectedValue + "'");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sbSQL.ToString(), conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            conn.Open();

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute the SQL command on the database   
            LiteralControl lit = new LiteralControl();
            lit.Text = String.Format("Data Uploaded Successfully.");
```

Thanks for all your help guys. 
I have decided to insert blank strings "" into the datbase instead of null now as it makes my life slightly easier when i run reports from it.

Comment: are you passing null to the database or are you passinf N/A?

Comment: Passing null (well trying to) the database should pick up the Drop Down List value not the Drop Down List text. But where I am defining the value as null in code it is taking the text instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if a `ListItem` has its value set to null, it will use the Text property as the value. For example this code:

```
ListItem l = new ListItem("Cats", null);

string s = l.Value;
```

The value of s is "Cats".

The solution is not to store null, but store an empty string, or -1, or something similar, and then check for this in your code.

Comment: Well I am using some other drop down lists too but i have defined all of their text and values in the web application. When I have set the Text to [N/A] and the value to '' it does exactly the same thing.. it still only sees the [N/A] text and writes that in. Whereas if i set the value to null in the same instance it recoginses it as a string which makes sense because of the way I have done the databse insert.

Comment: If you set the value to "" it will insert a blank string, not [N/A]. I have tested it with the code above, replacing null with "" and the value of s is an empty string. The other issue could be the strange (and potentially dangerous) way that you are building your SQL query. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293254/creating-safe-sql-statements-as-strings/293272#293272 and set your parameters in that way, not by using strings.

Comment: Ok i will check that out and implement. I have just been doing it this way because that is the way the business have taught me to do it.

Comment: The problem is if someone tries to inject malicious code into your SQL. If someone types their name in as "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--" then you could find your database getting completely erased. Using the method I linked to, C# will realise that someone is trying to do something naughty and either throw an exception, or insert the data as a string rather than executing it as a command.

Comment: Nobody has to type anything in the applciation at all. It all comes from a predfined drop down list that comes from another database. Does this make it any better?

Comment: Sadly not, I can edit the value of the dropdown box by using the F12 tool of internet explorer to put malicious code in, then when it is submitted, it could potentially wipe your SQL out. This is why it's always a good idea to use the built in methods to construct SQL. More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998271.aspx - In particular, look at "Step 2. Use Parameters with Stored Procedures" as this is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

A C# null is not the same as a database NULL.

In your insertion code you probably need to pick up that the value is "N/A"/null and then insert a DBNull instead. What does your DB insertion code look like?

Comment: I've put it in the question part now, does that helP?

Comment: Yep, and JDMX have written the code you can use in his answer. However, I'd suggest that it might be worth looking at using SqlParameters instead of your replacements.

Answer (score 0):

From my interpretation of C# ListItems, if the Value is not defined, then when you look up the Value, you'll get the Text. It's probably a simple `if (Value == null) return Text;` check, so naturally if you deliberately set the Value as null, it will then return the Text instead of your null value.

Another way to look at it is that you're calling the `new ListItem(string, string)` constructor, but passing a null value for the second argument. This basically calls `new ListItem(string)`, which likewise sets the Value to the Text. Mayhaps not literally, but the end result is the same.

**EDIT**

I did some testing of this in a simple situation. If you initialize a ListItem object with a `null` value for its Value, then both ListItem.Value and DropDownList.SelectedValue (when pointing at that list item) will get you the same value as your Text. As such, it can be inferred that initializing a ListItem with a `null` Value sets the Value to the same as the Text. Even setting it later to `null` via `ListItem.Value = null;` will still set it to the Text.

You will have to set the Value to some value, and instead of directly inputting the SelectedValue, run a check for if the SelectedValue equals this preset value. I personally use `_|NULL|_`.

*Code Snippet*

```
ListItem li;
li = new ListItem("Test", null);
Console.WriteLine(li.Value.ToString());
li.Value = null;
Console.WriteLine(li.Value.ToString());
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.Items.Add(li);
ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
Console.WriteLine(ddl.SelectedValue);
Console.ReadLine();
```

*Output*

```
Test
Test
Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DBNull.Value instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple do this:

```
sbSQL.Replace("@Trouser_S", (DDLTrous.SelectedValue == "[N/A]" ? "NULL" : "'" + DDLTrous.SelectedValue + "'"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to show how you are pulling the data off the drop down list and putting it into the db.  Use the SelectedItem property to get the ListItem ( you may have to cast it ) and then explicitly call the ListItem.Value for the db insert/update.

edit... doing for code

instead of

```
 sbSQL.Replace("@Trouser_S", "'" + DDLTrous.SelectedValue + "'");
```

do

```
ItemList il = (ItemList)DDLTrous.SelectedItem;
string s = il.Value;
if ( s != null )
  s = "'" + s + "'";
else
  s = "null";

sbSQL.Replace("@Trouser_S", s);
```

you might also try replacing null with "null" in the value.  But the key thing is that you cannot have the "'" + x + "'" around the null value otherwise it goes in as a string.

edit again..

if ItemList.Value cannot be null, then have the value be "null" and change the if statement.

```
ItemList il = (ItemList)DDLTrous.SelectedItem;
string s = il.Value;
if ( s != "null" )
  s = "'" + s + "'";

sbSQL.Replace("@Trouser_S", s);
```

Comment: Your if branch will only follow the top path because a ListItem's Value is automatically set to the same as its Text when it is set to `null`. This occurs both through the constructor and manual assignment.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, as you will not get a value of null.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I'm not sure if i have been ambiguous with my question and comments. But I want NULL to be inserted into the database.