# Must declare a scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I am getting the exception "Must declare the scalar variable"@strAccountID"

```
string @straccountid = string.Empty;

sSQL =
"SELECT GUB.BTN,
       GUP.CUST_USERNAME,
       GUP.EMAIL
FROM   GBS_USER_BTN         GUB,
       GBS_USER_PROFILE     GUP
WHERE  GUB.CUST_UID = GUP.CUST_UID
       AND GUB.BTN = '@straccountID'
ORDER BY
       CREATE_DATE DESC"

@straccountid = strAccountID.Substring(0, 10);
```

Code For running the query against the DB

```
    try
                {
                    oCn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GBRegistrationConnStr"].ToString());
                    oCn.Open();
                    oCmd = new SqlCommand();      
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strAccountID", strAccountID);  

                    oCmd.CommandText = sSQL;
                    oCmd.Connection = oCn;
                    oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    oDR = oCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

I already declared the variable. Is there any flaw in my query?

Comment: Where is the code where you declare the variable?

Comment: Wherever you declared it, SQL doesn't see it - your query should have a `DECLARE @strAccountID varchar(50)` or something similar, somewhere... is it a stored procedure?

Comment: Might be only a preference, but I find all-caps SQL is hard to read. Isn't `SELECT gub.Btn, gup.cust_UserName, gup.Email FROM gbs_USER_BTN gub, gbs_USER_PROFILE gup WHERE ...` easier on the eye?

Comment: @AdamPlocher I just added the code

Comment: Could you include the code where you are actually running the SQL statement against the database?

Comment: Add the code to your question, not on the comment.

Comment: @NicoleDesRosiers please see the code added to the Q

Comment: You need to pass that variable in to the SQL Command object as a parameter.

Comment: @MarkKram i tried still it is complainting about the same

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: @All So when the above code is executed when I see the value of SQL at ocmd.commandtext= sql,should I see the value or not.that is most confusing for me

Answer (score 2):

First off the bat get rid of these two lines:

```
string @straccountid = string.Empty;
@straccountid = strAccountID.Substring(0, 10);
```

and then try this code:

```
string strAccountID = "A1234"; //Create the variable and assign a value to it
string AcctID = strAccountID.Substring(0, 10);

oCn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GBRegistrationConnStr"].ToString());
oCn.Open();
oCmd = new SqlCommand();        

oCmd.CommandText = sSQL;
oCmd.Connection = oCn;
oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
ocmd.Parameters.Add("straccountid", AcctID); //<-- You forgot to add in the parameter
oDR = oCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

Here is a link on how to create Parametized Query: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: I like your answer more than my own, though we point in the same direction.  Trying to write these answers from an iPhone is somewhat less than easy :)

Comment: Thanks kram .I tried and ran the code and saw the output and still the value for that is not set:                                                                    SELECT  GUB.BTN,GUP.CUST_USERNAME,GUP.EMAIL from GBS_USER_BTN GUB,GBS_USER_PROFILE GUP WHERE GUB.CUST_UID = GUP.CUST_UID AND GUB.BTN = @straccountid ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC

Comment: Adrian you pointed him in the right direction and typing on an iPhone +1 for you!

Comment: I am sure that once we add the value to the command object the sql should pick up the value which is not happening.

Comment: @user1567194 - Are you assigning a value to the strAccountID variable?

Comment: yes here is the place where I am doing it :                                  ocmd.Parameters.Add("straccountid", strAccountID.Substring(0, 10))

Comment: No where are you assigning a value to the strAccountID variable before the Parameters.Add?

Comment: is that not the place where I am assiging the value?

Comment: @user1567194 That is the place where you are assigning the value in strAccountID to the Command Object's parameter object. Look at my code.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `@straccountid` but not as part of the SQL.  The SQL server only sees what you send to it.  You'd be better off using [SQLCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) and parameters to build your select statement safely.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293254/creating-safe-sql-statements-as-strings) has examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I used the same parametrized query and add the parameters with the tag "AddWithValue" to the cmd but if I see the statement oCmd.CommandText = sSQL;,When I am trying to check the value of @accuntId still the value is not getting assigned

Comment: Can you give an example of what your code looks like now?  When you execute the query are you still getting the same error?