# How to use the output statement and insert multiple values with that id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert values into two tables.

The first one looks like this

**Recipes**

```
RecipeId (unique and AI)
RecipeName
Method
Discontinued
```

The second one looks like this

**IngredientRecipe**

```
RecipeUniqId (unique and AI)
RecipeId (same as the RecipeId in the Recipes table)
IngredientId
```

I want to insert a RecipeName and a Method. If I do that the RecipeId gets auto incremented. Than I want to insert three times an ingredient with the RecipeId. Its working for one ingredient.

```
INSERT INTO Recipes (RecipeName, Method, Discontinued)
OUTPUT INSERTED.RecipeId, '5'
INTO IngredientRecipe(
    RecipeId,
    IngredientId
)

VALUES ('Potato and Chips', 'Potato and Chips bake everything', 'false');
```

So what I want is that I can add three times the same RecipeId with a different number for the IngredientId.

How to do this? I use sql server

EDIT:

I use asp.net with c# and an N-tier structure. I use a sql server database

Comment: Do you add recipe one by one?

Comment: I add the recipe one by one but I want to add for each recipe 3 ingredients so when you add a recipe I need the RecipeId and than the ingredientId. Just as my example but I want to add three ingredientId's with the recipeId.

Comment: then I think Karel's answer might be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable and store the value of the primary key used

```
declare @id int
```

Insert the data into `Receipes` table and use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function (see [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) for more)

```
 INSERT INTO Recipes (RecipeName, Method, Discontinued) VALUES (....)
 SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY
```

Repeatedly insert the ingredients using the value

```
INSERT INTO IngredientRecipe(RecipeId,  IngredientId) VALUES (@id, ...)
INSERT INTO IngredientRecipe(RecipeId,  IngredientId) VALUES (@id, ...)
...
```

Comment: Do I have to add all of these underneath each other in one big query?

Comment: You will have to generate it manualy in code and then execute. Please edit your answer so it will explain how this will be used - i.e. from app, what language, etc.

Comment: I use C# with asp.net and a sql server database

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293254/creating-safe-sql-statements-as-strings for inspiration. But you can just use `StringBuilder`, `SqlCommand` and do not forget to use `SqlParameter`, otherwise you will spend ages with escaping values.