# Very simple regex not working

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have [read](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/217-how-to-match-whole-words-with-a-regular-expression/) that to match a word inside of a string using Regular expressions (in .NET), I can use the word boundary specifier (`\b`) within the regex. However, none of these calls result in any matches

```
Regex.Match("INSERT INTO TEST(Col1,Col2) VALUES(@p1,@p2)", @"\b@p1\b");

Regex.Match("INSERT INTO TEST(Col1,Col2) VALUES(@p1,@p2)", @"\bINSERT\b");
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT:** The second one is already working ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**: As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544629/very-simple-regex-not-working/2544661#2544661) pointed out, `@` is not a word character so there is no word boundary between `@` and space. As a workaround, you could instead use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@"(?<!\w)@p1\b"
```

---

**Original answer**: You need a `@` in front of your regular expressions:

```
@"\b@p1\b"
```

Without this, the string "\b" is interpreted as a backspace (character 8), not a regular expression word boundary. There is more information about [@-quoted string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.71%29.aspx) literals on MSDN.

An alternative way without using @-quoted string literals is to escape your backslashes:

```
"\\b@p1\\b"
```

Answer (score 4):

The second case is solved by `@"\bINSERT\b"` as stated in another answer.

However `/b` matches at:

- Before the first character in the
  string, if the first character is a
  word character.
- After the last character in the
  string, if the last character is a
  word character.
- Between two characters in the string,
  where one is a word character and the
  other is not a word character.

A word character is one of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so the first case is not solvable by prefixing `@` to escape the `\b` character because you are trying to then match a non word character (`@`).

---

**Update:**
The first case can be solved by a negative look-behind assertion but also by using a negated word boundary `\B` which results in a more cleaner syntax (`@"\B@p1\b"`).

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out ;) Is there any way to overcome it ?

Comment: @Thomas Wanner, you can use Regular Expressions Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions. Check Mark Byers answer for a solution.

Comment: should write \b instead of /b above at "However..."

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is getting escaped in your strings - you need to use [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx) to avoid this:

```
@"\bINSERT\b"
```

Otherwise the regex sees `"bINSERTb"`.

Comment: Just had this problem, everything was working in my various external RegEx testers; just not in my code - I forgot the @.