# SQL Statement after adding parameters

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

Is it possible to see the sql statement after parameters have been replaced?

```
using(SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table(Value_fkey) VALUES(@ValueKey)", Database.Connection))
{
    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValueKey", ValueKey);
    System.Convert.ToInt32(cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

I'd like it to log my sql statements, so rather not via SQL Server, but I don't mind whether it is before, or after calling the statement.

Comment: Parameters don't really get 'replaced', they just get used as parameters. You can loop through the existing parameters and see their values at any time.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611446/what-sql-is-being-sent-from-a-sqlcommand-object

Comment: Use the profiler to see what happens.  You'll see one event prepare the statement, and another/others using that prepared statement, by ID.  There is no substitution.

Comment: The sql you are looking for does not exist, will **never** exist. That is the _whole point_ of using query parameters. Because this sql is never assembled, the chance of _data_ in your query being mistakenly interpreted as code is _zero_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the simplest way to do it then:

```
public void OutputSQLToTextFile(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{
        string query = sqlCommand.CommandText;
        foreach (SqlParameter p in sqlCommand.Parameters)
        {
            query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
        }
        OutputToTextFile(query);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is wrong when using parameter with composed names such as `@Par` and `@ParAdditional`. In this case the Replace method will replace `"@Par"` and so we could have in the second parameter [valuie]Additional.

Comment: @peterboccia What if you were to sort the parameters from longest to shortest before replacing?