# how do I debug SqlCommand Parameter.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, string, winforms, sqlcommand

I am using Parameters.AddWithValue to my SqlCommand variable.

I am able to dump the output to a textbox by saying

```
tb.Text = command.CommandText.ToString();
```

But it's not dumping the value for my parameter into the textbox.

Any suggestions on how to verify the parameters are "ok"?

I am using WinForm for Windows 8 using VS2012

Comment: view it on `Intellitrace`.

Comment: Check out my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611446/what-sql-is-being-sent-from-a-sqlcommand-object/2625184#2625184

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL parameters are sent to the server alongside the text of the command; they are not integrated with the CommandText.

You can examine the parameters by looking at the `Value` property in the `Parameters` collection.

Comment: How come the value is not being substituted?

Comment: @CocoaDev: Because that's not how SQL Server works.  The whole point of using parameters is that the value is **not** substituted; this makes it completely immune to SQL injection and allows the server to better reuse query plans.

Comment: So how can I be certain that the parameters values are being substituted. The reason I ask this is I am getting 0 results back. When I run the same exact query in SQL Management Studio, I get data back. Therefore I think one of 2 things. (A) The Parameters.AddWithValue is not being correctly used. (B) something with the how the code is being executed

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I didn't mean substituted for something else. I meant that it being swapped word0 with the actual value that was passed via Parameters