# IQueryable parameters - how to view?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have an LINQ-to-SQL (IQueryable) query, which I need to debug as it's horrendously slow. I've managed to get the T-SQL from the query (by simply hovering over the IQueryable object after I put a breakpoint in), but the query uses parameters such as @p1, @p2 etc - some of which are a mystery to me (usually ones in a COALESCE function). Is there anyway to view these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve LINQ to sql statement (IQueryable) WITH parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343754/retrieve-linq-to-sql-statement-iqueryable-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio Magazine suggest a Visual Studio Extension called **LInQ to Entities Debug Visualizer**.

> RV's Linq to Entity query visualizer is Visual Studio addin.  This
> helps visualize details of debugged LInQ query with
>
> 1. Lambda expression.
> 2. Native SQL.
> 3. Edit query parameters
> 4. Connection properties.
> 5. Query execution log.
> 6. Option to export query result to MS Excel file.

You can download it [here](http://rajavenkatesh.com/)