# How to specify a wildcard in a SQL Server Table Adapter query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wildcard, tableadapter

I am trying to figure out how to specify a wildcard in a SQL server table adapter query. I have already been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781801/how-to-get-the-executing-sql-query-from-a-table-adapter), and searched elsewhere on the Microsoft tech sites, and cannot find an appropriate example.

I have a table adapter query that is supposed to return a single value (a particular query choice in the table adapter query wizard) based on a `WHERE` clause with two parameters. Here is the query out of the table adapter, which works just fine testing the query in the `Query Builder` and using SQL Management Studio writing a query for the particular database table.

```
SELECT     owner_name_1
FROM         BuildingPermit.dbo.real_estate
WHERE     (prop_addr_no like ?) AND (prop_addr_str = ?)
```

To make a fine point, the query above is in the adapter. In my example 11% and ACADEMY ST are being passed to the query as parameters.

Basically, if the `WHERE` parameters are *11-11A* and *ACADEMY ST*, I get back a non-null value when testing, but not in my C# program.

Here is a C# handler, which does not work.

```
private void owner_cb_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string str_no = street_number_cb.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "%"; 
  string str_name = street_name_cb.Text.Trim().ToUpper();

  string owner_name_1 = (string )real_estateTableAdapter1.owner_name_1_q(str_no,            str_name));
  owner_cb.Text = owner_name_1;
}
```

### Update:

I have tried a full row query with the same results.

```
DataTable re_tbl = real_estateTableAdapter1.get_re_rec_by_str_num_name_q(search_street_number, street_name_cb.Text.ToString().ToUpper());

// Break after one loop. Only one answer expected.                
foreach (DataRow dr in re_tbl.Rows)
{
    string temp_val = (string)dr["owner_name_1"];
    owner_cb.Text = temp_val;
    break;
```

}

I get back a null.

I have also tried bracketing the parameter containing 11% (from my example) with sinqle quotes, and that does not work either.

And I have tried this, and the QueryBuilder won't parse it.

```
SELECT     owner_name_1
FROM         BuildingPermit.dbo.real_estate
WHERE     (prop_addr_no LIKE @p1) AND (prop_addr_str = @p2)
```

Comment: where is real_estateTableAdapter1 instantiated?

Comment: Try debugging. Create a breakpoint on line where you call .owner_name_1_q function. Do passed values look OK? If there is no problem try checking what SQL Server really received (using SQL Server Profiler or something similar).

Comment: @chris544 The values look OK, so I'm going to try pulling back full rows based on the same criteria. This is a return 1 value query in the table adapter.

Comment: Try selecting something with no conditions, like <SELECT 'abc'>.

Comment: @chris544 Done that as well. I'm trying a full-width (all columns) query using the original criteria, `LIKE` for the street number.

Comment: I've tested this and it works

Comment: In (prop_addr_no like ?) AND (prop_addr_str = ?) you have "@p1" and "@p2" instead of "?" right?

Comment: @216 Will not parse in the Query Builder. I found those examples and tried them, and I'll go try it again. I did not see the '\' in front of the '@'.

Comment: @216 Won't parse. I updated the OP. It won't parse on the \@.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did, and it worked, I hope it's useful to you.

1.- In Dataset designer right click table adapter, add query

[image]

2.- Use SQL Satatements

3.- Select which returns a single value

4.- Open Query builder, It looks like this:

[image]

5.- And in my test I did get a value:
[image]