# Show CommandText from SQLCommand with All Parameter value

Tags: c#, messagebox

I Want to display the `CommandText` of `SqlCommand` with all parameter value..

When I Use,

```
MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
```

The `messagebox` just display,

```
ex: "insert into nasabah values(@nama,@kontak)"
```

I Want, the messagebox show the query with all parameter values, example:

```
"insert into nasabah ('Deni','021899999');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the generated SQL-Statement from a SqlCommand-Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object)

Comment: just traverse the cmd.Parameters collection, then you will get all the parameters.

Comment: The parameters are **not** getting substituted into the SQL command text - that's why you're not seeing them. The parameters are sent to SQL Server along side the SQL command text. If you want to show the SQL command text with the actual values, you have to replace the parameter placeholders with the values yourself