# 2nd Date Parameter Throws ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oraclecommand

I have a query where I need to check a date between two dates using Oracle.  Whenever I run the code I get an ORA-01843: not a valid month error.  However whenever I remove either of the two parameters from the sql it works fine, but trying to use two date parameters throw an error.  What am I missing?

```
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        DateTime yearBegin = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(taxYear) + 1, 1, 1);
        DateTime yearEnd = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(taxYear) + 1, 12, 31);
        sql.Append(
            "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = '1099' AND CREATED_DT >= TO_DATE(:createdYearBegin, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND CREATED_DT <= TO_DATE(:createdYearEnd, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND SSN = :ssn");
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cubsConnection"]))
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql.ToString(), cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ssn", ssn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("createdYearBegin", yearBegin.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("createdYearEnd", yearEnd.ToShortDateString());
                cn.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                ret = dr.HasRows;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Dates come out correct when watching in a debugger, and if it was a problem with the result of ToShortDateString() than it would have the same issue whether there was one or two date parameters, but since if I remove one, or the other date parameter, and run it with just one of the parameters it works fine.

Comment: So could you see what's the sql generated with both dates ? Example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object

Comment: The sql is as expected (Although I had to add the single quotes around the dates:   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = '1099' AND CREATED_DT >= TO_DATE('1/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND CREATED_DT <= TO_DATE('12/31/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND SSN = 'ssnNumber'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think you've got a problem with your parameter's order.

If you don't bind parameters by name, they are bound by position (means the order in which you add parameters is taken).

Just try to add :

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

Comment: The Dates come out correct, and if it was a problem with the result of ToShortDateString() than it would have the same issue whether there was one or two date parameters, but since if I remove one, or the other date parameter, and run it with just one of the parameters it works fine.

Comment: @UnHolyRam I found something else, could you give a try ?

Comment: We have a winner.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You expect date formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY`, but it is not guaranteed that `ToShortDateString()` returns it in this format. A format specifiction is needed. But well, I do not even know what is the programming language you are using to provide further help...

Answer (score 0):

Print out the results of ToShortDateString and you'll see what happens. Also, i agree with "you should provide a format because you can't rely on the default".

Comment: DateTime in c# working with 0 to 11 ? Really ? Where does this come from ?

Comment: Looked like Java to me, and the OP didn't provide a language tag. Removed that part of my answer.