# Error when trying to run a stored procedure with data from Excel in a telerik coded step

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I am trying to run a SQL Server stored procedure which takes input parameters from a excel sheet and it is throwing me an error.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'CreatedDate DESC'

[image]

Code:

```
string SP = "dbEmail_Message_GetMessageListForFolder";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SP, conn);

cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

string myPath = @"C:\Users\Monica\Desktop\ExcelTest.xlsx";
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);

// select the correct worksheet
Excel.Worksheet demoWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

excelApp.Visible = false;

// select the right cell in the correct worksheet
// var value = Convert.ToString(demoWorksheet.get_Range("E2", "E2").Value2) ;
// file2.WriteLine("value=" + value);       
// file2.Close();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@strCurrentUser", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@strCurrentUser"].Value = '"'+Convert.ToString(demoWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "A2").Value2)+'"';

cmd.Parameters.Add("@intCurrentSite", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@intCurrentSite"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("B2", "B2").Value2; 

cmd.Parameters.Add("@intStatus", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@intStatus"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("C2", "C2").Value2;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@blnSentMailOnly", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@blnSentMailOnly"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("D2", "D2").Value2;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@strSortBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@strSortBy"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("E2", "E2").Value2;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@intToSite", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@intToSite"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("F2", "F2").Value2;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubCategory", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@SubCategory"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("G2", "G2").Value2;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPageIndex", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@intPageIndex"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("H2", "H2").Value2;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@strToUserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@strToUserName"].Value = '"' + Convert.ToString(demoWorksheet.get_Range("I2", "I2").Value2) + '"';

cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPageSize", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@intPageSize"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("J2", "J2").Value2;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Category"].Value = '"' + Convert.ToString(demoWorksheet.get_Range("K2", "K2").Value2) + '"';

SqlParameter rowCount = cmd.Parameters.Add("@intTotalRecords", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
rowCount.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader alertReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();

excelApp.Workbooks.Close();
int count = 0;

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Monica\\Documents\\source.txt");

if (alertReader.HasRows)
{
    while (alertReader.Read())
    {
        count = count + 1;
        file.WriteLine("DB Alert Count is:" + count);
    }

    alertReader.Close();
}
```

I have another test script which runs the same stored procedure with input values directly provided in the test script which works fine.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

        string SP = "dbEmail_Message_GetMessageListForFolder";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SP, conn);

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strCurrentUser", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@strCurrentUser"].Value = "derek";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@intCurrentSite", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@intCurrentSite"].Value = 19;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@intStatus", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@intStatus"].Value = 0;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@blnSentMailOnly", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@blnSentMailOnly"].Value = 0;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strSortBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@strSortBy"].Value = "CreatedDate DESC";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@intToSite", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@intToSite"].Value = 12;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubCategory", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@SubCategory"].Value = "RouteToPCPRequest";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPageIndex", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@intPageIndex"].Value = 1;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strToUserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@strToUserName"].Value = "hunterjane";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPageSize", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@intPageSize"].Value = 100;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Category"].Value = "OnlineNotification";

        SqlParameter rowCount = cmd.Parameters.Add("@intTotalRecords", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        rowCount.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader alertReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The whole error log is pasted below:

Failure Information: 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Exception thrown executing coded step: '[VerifyAlerts_CodedStep2] : Verify number of 'divs' equal to number of 'alerts''.
InnerException:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'CreatedDate DESC'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TrySetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Communicator.Alerts.Alerts_VerifyDivsCount_WithDatabase.Alerts_VerifyDivsCount_WithDatabase__Copy_CodedStep() in c:\tfs\HASINC\Development\QAAutomation\Communicator\Alerts\Alerts_VerifyDivsCount_WithDatabase - Copy.tstest.cs:line 123
ClientConnectionId:a4f49f47-65aa-4e0d-af2c-8791d3f2f610

Can Someone please let me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

CreatedDate DESC looks like it should be in the ORDER BY clause not in the list of column names but I don't see the SQL code which is where the exception is coming from..

Comment: when i direvtly give the input as this 
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@strSortBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@strSortBy"].Value = "CreatedDate DESC"; It works.

Comment: but when I am trying to do something like   cmd.Parameters.Add("@strSortBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@strSortBy"].Value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("E2", "E2").Value2; it throws the error

Comment: Check the type of Value2. Is it a string?

Comment: may also want to see this thread to see what the SQL is that is generated:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object

Comment: aha!
The only difference between Value2 property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.


i just read this when you gave me a hint to check the Value2.
I am using it for date column.. so I think that is where the problem is

Comment: I will try doing a .Value and check.