# Is there any possibilities to show the query with all parameters value in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

Say we have a query where I will add some parameters

For Ex:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table(UserName, Password, Country, Email) values(@UserName, @Password, @Country, @Email)", con);

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User.UserName);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", User.Password);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", User.Country);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", User.Email);
```

Something like this.

Now I want to display the query result like

```
insert into Table(UserName, Password, Country, Email) 
values('Test1', '1234', 'India', 'abc@xyz.com')
```

The values shown will be the parameters that I added.

As far as I know in `php` when we **echo** the query and run it in browser we will get the value of parameters. But is there any possibilities here?.

Answer (score 1):

SQL command text and parameters are send to sql server separately, you can't get the final sql statement using SqlCommand, try using SQL Profiler.

Comment: So, we cant view the values in VS 2010 then?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object