# Stored procedure not returning same results as constructed SQL string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# console application that generates reports from a SQL Server database. All of my reports are based off of stored procedures, and my app code calls the stored procedures all the same way.

I have come across an issue where one stored procedure is not functioning in my app the way it is expected to, despite the stored procedure functioning as expected when run from SQL Server Management Studio.

I am at my wits' end trying to resolve this issue. I've dissected it as many different ways as I can, had a few extra pair of eyes examine this code, and still I can't get this to work.

```
// code in my app
public DataTable DeviceAuthorizationAffectedDeviceGroup(string affectedDeviceGroupNameArray, DateTime startDate, int deviceId) {
    dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    string sql = "SELECT StartTime EventTime, EventText, UserName AS Username, AffectedDeviceGroupName";
    sql += " FROM eventlog";
    sql += " WHERE AffectedDeviceGroupName IN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) FROM dbo.SplitString('" + affectedDeviceGroupNameArray + "', ','))";
    sql += " AND StartTime >= '" + startDate + "'";
    sql += " AND (DeviceID = " + deviceId + ")";
    sql += " ORDER BY StartTime";

    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString)) {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                Debug.WriteLine(MyDamnClass.CommandAsSql(cmd));
                da.Fill(dt);  //SQL string, data table contains 6 rows
            }
        }

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_REPORTS_SubReport_GetDeviceAuthorizationAffectedDeviceGroup_TEST", cn)) {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AffectedDeviceGroupNameArray", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = affectedDeviceGroupNameArray;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = deviceId;

                Debug.WriteLine(MyDamnClass.CommandAsSql(cmd));
                da.Fill(dt2);  //stored proc, data table contains 0 rows
            }
        }
    }

    return dt;
}   // breakpoint here to examine the contents of each data table
```

Stored procedure on the server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_REPORTS_SubReport_GetDeviceAuthorizationAffectedDeviceGroup_TEST]
     (@AffectedDeviceGroupNameArray varchar(MAX), 
      @StartTime datetime, @DeviceID int) 
AS
    SELECT 
        StartTime EventTime,
        EventText,
        UserName AS Username,
        AffectedDeviceGroupName
    FROM
        eventlog
    WHERE 
        AffectedDeviceGroupName IN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) 
                                    FROM dbo.SplitString(@AffectedDeviceGroupNameArray, ','))
        AND StartTime >= @StartTime
        AND (DeviceID = @DeviceID)
    ORDER BY 
        StartTime
```

SQL code being executed from my app (using @Flapper's code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object))

```
use MyDatabase;
SELECT 
    StartTime EventTime, EventText, UserName AS Username, 
    AffectedDeviceGroupName 
FROM 
    eventlog 
WHERE 
    AffectedDeviceGroupName IN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) 
                                FROM dbo.SplitString('(Unassigned)', ','))   
    AND StartTime >= '10/12/2015 2:46:51 PM' 
    AND (DeviceID = 281) 
ORDER BY 
    StartTime

use MyDatabase;
declare @return_value int;
exec [usp_REPORTS_SubReport_GetDeviceAuthorizationAffectedDeviceGroup_TEST]
    @AffectedDeviceGroupNameArray = '(Unassigned)'
    , @StartTime = '10/12/2015 2:46:51 PM'
    , @DeviceID = 281
;
select 'Return Value' = convert(varchar, @return_value);
```

What am I not seeing? What is causing the stored procedure to not return rows when the identical constructed SQL string returns what I expect it to? I'm sure it's something small, and will cause one of those "d'oh!" moments once it's pointed out.

Comment: You really should be using a parameterized query. String contactination is not reliable, switch your text version to use parameters and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I wonder if in your C# code the DateTime is being coerced into a String (because of the concatenation) whereas when you're calling the stored procedure it's being passed as a DateTime (through the parameter.)

Comment: You should also use the date format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss` with string literals, other formats are language / setting specific. Not sure if that's the reason here or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference between the select statement that you built by concatenating strings and the execution of the stored procedure is the data type of your parameters that you are comparing.  Depending on the datatype of your table fields, this could alter results between the methods.  In particular, you will get different results if the `StartTime` field in your `eventlog` table is varchar instead of datetime.

In your select query you are comparing the StartTime field to a string literal:

```
StartTime >= '" + startDate + "'";
```

If `StartTime` is a varchar type, this would result in a string comparison instead of a date comparison, which would not be what you intended.  It would sort dates alphabetically, so for example '10/12/2015 2:46:51 PM' would be greater than '01/12/2016 2:46:51 PM' because it starts with a 1 and the other with a 0.

However when you compare the `StartTime` field to the parameter in the stored procedure it is comparing the data as datetime.  Due to data type precedence, it will try to do an implicit conversion of the table field to a datetime data type and then compare the two as dates.

If you do an explicit conversion to datetime of either the StartTime field or the string parameter you should get the same results with both methods:

```
convert(datetime, StartTime) >= '" + startDate + "'";
```