# return sql query with parameter

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I want to return my sql query with parameters assigned, but I can't. Can you explain how I can return the parameters as defined?

```
public string InsertText(string Ad, string Soyad, string OkulNo, int RolId, string TelNo)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO kutuphane.kisiler (Adi,Soyadi,No,RolId,TelNo) VALUES (@Adi,@Soyadi,@No,@RolId,@TelNo)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Adi", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Ad;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Soyadi", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Soyad;
            command.Parameters.Add("@OkulNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OkulNo;
            command.Parameters.Add("@RolId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = RolId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TelNo;
            return command.CommandText;
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object Similar question with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. A parameterized query is more than just a `string`. If you are expecting to see the parameters replaced in the query: *that's not what parameters are*. I'd probably just return `command` here, and have the caller execute it (after setting the connection). Or just execute it inside the method and never have the query leave.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about my answer...
but have you tried to do this?

```
    public MySqlCommand InsertText(string Ad, string Soyad, string OkulNo, int RolId, string TelNo)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO kutuphane.kisiler (Adi,Soyadi,No,RolId,TelNo) VALUES (@Adi,@Soyadi,@No,@RolId,@TelNo)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Adi", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Ad;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Soyadi", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Soyad;
            command.Parameters.Add("@OkulNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OkulNo;
            command.Parameters.Add("@RolId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = RolId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TelNo;
            return command;
        }
```

You can have MySqlCommand return directly instead of the string.
Remember that later you have to print the query in string format, as you did previously